# Magento Reindex - Vanishes all products from front-end

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I've moved a Magento Store from a server to another (different link also). Everything is working fine like Cart, Pages, Categories, etc. but PRODUCT PAGES gives me a 404 error.

I've read articles over the internet so I tried to reindex everything. When I do that all products vanishes from the front-end. They are still there in the admin.

Cache is erased & disabled.

Someone can help me with this?

Comment: What do you see in `exception.log`?

Comment: This might be a stupid question but where do I find this file? I can find only 'system.log' in /var/log

Comment: If you don't have it and you have it defined in your `Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Enabled` = `Yes` and `Exceptions Log File Name` = `exception.log`, then that means the system isn't recording any exceptions.

Comment: Hi. Managed to get it. Here is the exception.log : http://pastebin.com/STM2yS15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you imported your database with phpMyAdmin after moving servers then you should look at the values in `core_store`.  Make sure the `admin` `store_id` is `0`.  Sometimes when reimporting using phpMyAdmin that value can get set to `1` instead and mess things up a bit.  If it won't let you change it then create a new one with the `id` set to `0`

`EDIT`

Restore your log_url table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log_url` (
  `url_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `visitor_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `visit_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`url_id`),
  KEY `IDX_VISITOR` (`visitor_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='URL visiting history';
```

Comment: Hi! Checked and store_id for admin is set to 0.

Comment: Does your new server have `mod_rewrite` enabled?  If not, then you should send a support request in to get it turned on.  If you're on a virtual dedicated or dedicated server then you can enable it yourself by going to your `http.conf` file and uncommenting the line that looks like `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` or any line that has `mod_rewrite.so` in it, save the file and restart apache.  If you don't see this then look up instructions for enabling it for your specific server platform.

Comment: Hi again. Yes it has is on because the rest works. This problem with 404 appears on product pages only.

Comment: Go to `Admin -> Configuration -> Manage Stores`.  Select your store under `Store Name` then re-select your root category.  Save and re-index.  I apologize for all these troubleshooting steps but without any type of log output I'm just running through anything I can think of :)

Comment: Not working. If it helps you, here is an exception log: http://pastebin.com/STM2yS15

Comment: Try restoring your log_url table by adding this via phpMyAdmin or other mysql interface (see answer edit).  I don't think it will fix your product display problem but it will get rid of that exception.  If this table is missing then is it possible that you're missing more?  `log_url` can get pretty large and can time out on imports.  Verify the number of tables that you have in your current install match what you had on your old server.

Comment: It really does seem that your site didn't get transferred completely.  Even though it's partially working I would bet that you're missing tables.  Is there any way for you to compare them (old vs new)?

Comment: There were tables missing in the DB. Thanks. I will award your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If pages are giving you a 404 after a server transfer, check your:

1. .htaccess files
2. apache settings/magento URL rewrite configuration setting
3. template files to ensure they are using the $this->getUrl('') url generators (some themes have hard coded links)

Since the error is occuring on reindex, I'm inclined to say that your Apache or Magento URL rewrites aren't configured correctly with this new server.

Comment: 1. ".htaccess" is fine. Double checked it and everything else like Categories, Pages, Cart, etc. is working.

2. I don't know what do you mean by that.

3. Template is fine